# Is it acceptable to comparatively interpret regression coefficients from two different models?

Tags: regression

I am regressing D.V on 6 I.V using OLS. The objective is interpretation of coefficients and not predictions.

My D.V. is collected monthly and it is hypothesized that these 6 I.V. have different effect on D.V. depending upon the season.

Would it be statistically logical to do 4 separate regression models (Summer, Winter, Fall, Spring) and comparatively interpret coefficient. For example, if B1 for summer is 4 but 2 for fall and insignificant in other, is statement that "IV 1 is positively related to DV in summer & fall, but the effect is half in fall to that in summer" logical?

If not, are their other techniques to this type of data analysis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fit a single model including the interaction terms between the categorical season variable and your six independent variables. Suitable combinations of the coefficients from this model will answer your question.

If you happen to work in R, these calculations are streamlined in the **[effects](https://cran.r-project.org/package=effects)** and **[emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans)** packages.